# Click a link to display a value

Tags: php

I have a shoutbox/ chatroom feature on my site.
I have a list of online users on the left. 
I plan on making a button for each user that when clicked, puts their username into the typing area on the shoutbox.

Whats the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: This is not PHP related, but more like Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You want it so when you click their name, it's appended to a text field? You can just do:

```
<span onClick="document.getElementById('shoutbox').text += 'test-username';">test-username</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the links to JavaScript. PHP can't help you here.